# executor Service interupt handling

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application in which there are multiple threads. I want them to execute in order.so i choose executorService for multi-threading. if any one of thread(run method) is in error , I want to move on to net thread so that by the end i can come to know how many thread are completed successfully (count needed).My sample code:

The Main class:

```
     public class MySampleClass{
       ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
           for(int i=0; i<=100;i++){    
             executor.submit(new ThreadClass());
           }
//After all threads executed now to shutdown executor
executor.shutdown()
executor.awaitForTermination(1,Time.MILLISECONDS);
```

My Sample Thread Class :

```
public class ThreadClass implements Runnable{
      @override
      public void run(){
             boolean isCompleted= doAction();
             if(!isCompleted){
                   // I want here to stop this thread only..what to do ?
                  //executor.shutdown will stop all other threads  
               }
       }
}
```

Any Suggestion what to do ?? Am i doing it wrong way ?

Comment: Why don't you just `return;`?

Comment: Those are not threads, those are _tasks_.  A task is a piece of work that needs to be done.  Your `SingleThreadExecutor` is an object that uses a thread to execute your tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

You shouldn't stop a thread. There is a [reason](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) Thread.stop is deprecated. Instead you can interrupt the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Callable instead of Runnable. If you do that, submit method returns a Future (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instance on which you can verify if the callable do it´s work in the right way. The documentation explains it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)

Hope i explained in the right way.